# Empty "Parsed-HTML" field on using "invoke-webrequest" in Azure Powershell Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am trying to make a rest API call using "invoke-webrequest" in azure powershell runbook.

At first, I got the error message regarding the Internet Explorer Engine. When I searched about it, I found that using `**-UseBasicParsing**` would solve the problem. However, after using it, I am not facing the error message anymore but I am getting empty "`**Parsed-Html**`".
The code is running fine when I am running it locally.

```
$result = invoke-webrequest -uri $url -Headers $Header -UseBasicParsing
```

I expect the output of Parsed-Html to be an object, but it is null.

Answer (score 1):

In Automation, when we use cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest we need to use the–UseBasicParsing option as we do not have the Internet Explorer in Azure Automation sandboxes.

In this scenario you should use `**HtmlAgilityPack**`. Upload the `**HtmlAgilityPack.dll**` as module and use command "`add-type -Path .\HtmlAgilityPack.dll` " in runbook to generate the `**HtmlDocument**`

Code would look something like below:

```
$URI = "https://www.google.fr/search?q=googe&rlz=1C1CHBF_frFR711FR711&oq=googe&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.912j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=google"    


$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient    
$htmlString=$wc.DownloadString($URI)    


cd C:\Modules\User\HtmlAgilityPack    
add-type -Path .\HtmlAgilityPack.dll    
$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument   


$doc.LoadHtml($htmlString)    
$root= $doc.DocumentNode    
$root.SelectSingleNode("//head/title").Innertext
```

You can check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/eaadff1f-7bfc-49be-9e9a-3139c3dbe473/invoke-web-request-return-empty-parsed-html-field?forum=azureautomation) for further reference.
Hope it helps.